# Looking to see if a particular character exists in a string SAS

Tags: sas

I am working with customer data, part of which looks at customers email addresses. Unfortunately there are next to none controls on fields where customer data is input in the system and therefore requires scrubbing.

Using the current email field, I want to create a new field populated with the customer's email address based on the condition "if @ exists" and then if it doesn't exist, I will populate the email address with a blank value.

For example:

```
  Current Email Address               New Email Address
  customer1@business1.com             customer1@business1.com
  customer2@business2.com             customer2@business2.com
  customer3business3.com
```

Can anyone help - I have scoured the internet and cannot find anything that would do this!!

Thanks

Comment: INDEX/FIND are what you need. You can search lexjansen.com for examples of cleaning data including email addresses. There's a lot of sample code on there.

Comment: FYI - your question is likely being downvoted since it doesn't meet the requirements for SO - you need to show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably want more controls than this to validate an email address, but here you go:

```
data have;
infile cards;
input cur_email:$50.;
cards4;
customer1@business1.com 
customer2@business2.com
customer3business3.com
;;;;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  if index(cur_email,"@") then new_email=cur_email;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for a string within the email address like 'gmail' then you can use this:

```
if COMPRESS(TRANWRD(cur_email,'gmail','~'),'~','k')='~' then new_email=cur_email;
```

or to be in keeping with the first answer:

```
if INDEX(TRANWRD(cur_email,'gmail','~'),'~') then new_email=cur_email;
```